# how to make particular column of datagrid a combobox when AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM . I am using wpf with MVVM in my project . So I am testing things right now before diving into an app I need to write.

My page (EmpDetailsWindow.xaml) is like this

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgEmployee" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDataTable}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsReadOnly="False"  />
    <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" CommandParameter="sample param" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

and my model (EmpDetailsWindowViewModel) is as below

```
public class EmpDetailsWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }
        public EmpDetailsWindowViewModel()
        {
            EmployeeDataTable = DataTableCreator.EmployeeDataTable();
            GenderDataTable = DataTableCreator.GenderDataTable();
            SubmitCommand = new SubmitCommand();
        }

        DataTable _employeeDataTable;
        public DataTable EmployeeDataTable
        {
            get { return _employeeDataTable;}
            set
            {
                _employeeDataTable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EmployeeDataTable");
            }
        }

        DataTable _genderDataTable;
        public DataTable GenderDataTable
        {
            get { return _genderDataTable; }
            set
            {
                _genderDataTable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GenderDataTable");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

datagrid is successfully bound to the datatable . Now I have a column "Gender" in datagrid. This should be a combobox and the item source of the cobobox is got from GenderDataTable of the view model . How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>

private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Gender")
    {
        var cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        cb.ItemsSource = (DataContext as MyVM).GenderDataTable;
        cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Gender");
        e.Column = cb;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Infragistics grid dont support this event ? wat to do for dat case ?

Comment: Well if it doesn't really support any equivalent event, i would contact Infragistics to ask what's wrong with them, then proceed disabling the auotgeneration of column and define them explicitly

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to quite be a complete answer here so I'll post what I found from this question and from experimentation. I'm sure this breaks many rules but it's simple and it works

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // define a dictionary (key vaue pair). This is your drop down code/value
        public static Dictionary<string, string> 
              dCopyType = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                 { "I", "Incr." }, 
                 { "F", "Full" } 
              };


// If you autogenerate columns, you can use this event 
// To selectively override each column
// You need to define this event on the grid in the event tab in order for it to be called
private void Entity_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,
                                         DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {

            // The name of the database column
            if (e.PropertyName == "CopyType")
            {
                // heavily based on code above
                var cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                cb.ItemsSource = dCopyType;  // The dictionary defined above
                cb.SelectedValuePath = "Key";  
                cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
                cb.Header = "Copy Type"; 
                cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("CopyType");
                e.Column = cb;
            }


        }
  } // end public partial class MainWindow
```